# Corrupt .photoslibrary file in Photos app. Any way to get photos back?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, file-transfer, filesystem

I am using Apple's **Photos** app on macOS El Capitan.

When trying to copy my `Photos Library.photoslibrary` file (44 gigs) from old external drive to new internal drive, I get a `-36` error. Apparently the file is corrupt.

Are all my photos lost? Are those photos stored externally as files somewhere else on the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Finder**, right-click the `Photos Library.photoslibrary` file and click `Show Package Contents`. Inside you will find a folder named `Masters`. It contains all your originals, organized by date. If you’ve made no edits to your photos, then that’s all you need.

If copying `Masters` fails, you can try copying individual subfolders until you’ve isolated the corrupted folders/photos. This will at least allow you to salvage the vast majority of your photos, instead of losing the entire library.

The `-36` error in **Finder** is often caused by corrupt `.` files (typically `.DS_Store`). Thankfully there is a handy command-line utility named `dot_clean` that will attempt to fix this issue for you. It’s a good idea to have a backup of your photos before using any repair tool, so do this after you’ve copied your `Masters` folder somewhere safe.

Open a **Terminal** session and type the following:
`dot_clean ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/`
This is assuming your Photos Library is in the default location. Since you’re using an external drive, replace `~/Pictures` with the correct path (prefixing spaces with `\`).

Now try copying your `Photos Library.photoslibrary` file once again. If this still fails, try repairing your external drive using **Disk Utility** and running **First Aid** on it.

And as a last resort, you can try repairing your Photos Library. Quit out of **Photos** completely by pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>. Then relaunch the app by holding <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd> while clicking the icon in your dock. Finally choose `Repair`.

Leave the app alone while it does its thing and don't interact with it in any way.